# How to upload only updated files in Google Apps Script using clasp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, push, add-on, clasp

I'm developing Google Apps Script **locally**. I used the **clasp push --watch** command for **pushing** updated code to the original Apps Script as per the **documentation**.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/clasp#push

The problem is that when I **update** the code of any **one file**, it uploads the **whole file**. I have attached the screenshot of the **file structure** and **vs code terminal**.
You can see there I had updated the code of **home.html** but still, it's uploaded the **whole project**. Because of this, we are getting **time-consuming issues**. It's taking a **long time** to upload the project. I had also attached the screen shot of clasp.json file.

Is there any way to upload the **only updated file ?**

[image: Pushed Files]

[image: Folder Struture]

[image: Clasp.json]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this behavior is expected based on the documentation:

> **Warning:** Google scripts APIs do not currently support atomic nor per file operations. Thus the push command always replaces the whole content of the online project with the files being pushed.

> **clasp** **push** replaces code that is on script.google.com and **clasp** **pull**
> replaces all files locally. For this reason, follow these guidelines:
>
> Do not concurrently edit code locally and on script.google.com. Use a
> version control system, like git.

A new feature would be required from the Google Apps Script API to accomplish what you're looking for, it seems there is already a Feature Request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/231616121), you can vote for it, add your comments and look for any future updates.

##### References

- [Pulling & Pushing Files](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/clasp#4)
- [Feature request: clasp push -w - add option to push only changed files](https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/760)
- [Problems when using CLASP to push client-side files from a local editor](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/4KsKbQrqYzk)